# User defined datatypes CANNOT be returned in web service in Jboss 5.0.1

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web

I am using Jboss 5.0.1, jdk 1.6.0 update 31 and implementing an EJB as a web service and my method in web service module returns an Array of JavaBean objects in my example BenefitLevel array object. When executed in JBoss it throws the following exception:

```
    08:57:08,552 ERROR [ServiceProxy] Service error
    javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException: Cannot create proxy
          at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxrpc.client.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:359)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
           at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxrpc.client.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:127)
           at $Proxy105.getCarrierWSSEIPort(Unknown Source)
           at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:92)
           at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
            at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
           at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
              at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
           at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
           at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
           at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
           at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
          at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
          at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
          at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:601)
          at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot synchronize to any of these methods:
      public abstract stubs.BenefitLevel[] stubs.CarrierWSSEI.getActiveBenData() throws java.rmi.RemoteException

    OperationMetaData:
      qname={urn:CarrierWS/wsdl}getActiveBenData
     javaName=getActiveBenData
     style=rpc/literal
     oneWay=false
     soapAction=
     ReturnMetaData:
      xmlName=result
     partName=result
      xmlType={urn:CarrierWS/types/arrays/com/test/cas/carrier/plan/info}BenefitLevelArray
      javaType=com.benefitpartnersinc.cas.carrier.plan.info.BenefitLevel[]
       mode=OUT
      inHeader=false
        index=-1
            at org.jboss.ws.metadata.umdm.OperationMetaData.eagerInitialize(OperationMetaData.java:491)
             at org.jboss.ws.metadata.umdm.EndpointMetaData.eagerInitializeOperations(EndpointMetaData.java:557)
            at org.jboss.ws.metadata.umdm.EndpointMetaData.initializeInternal(EndpointMetaData.java:541)
            at org.jboss.ws.metadata.umdm.EndpointMetaData.setServiceEndpointInterfaceName(EndpointMetaData.java:220)
             at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxrpc.client.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:345)
            ... 33 more
            08:57:08,567 ERROR [STDERR] javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException: Cannot create proxy
           08:57:08,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxrpc.client.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:359)
          08:57:08,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
          08:57:08,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
         08:57:08,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
         08:57:08,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
         08:57:08,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxrpc.client.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:127)
          08:57:08,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at $Proxy105.getCarrierWSSEIPort(Unknown Source)
            08:57:08,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:92)
           08:57:08,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        08:57:08,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
       08:57:08,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
      08:57:08,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
       08:57:08,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
        08:57:08,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
      08:57:08,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
      08:57:08,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        08:57:08,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
        08:57:08,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
       08:57:08,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
      08:57:08,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
      08:57:08,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
      08:57:08,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
      08:57:08,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
      08:57:08,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
   08:57:08,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
     08:57:08,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    08:57:08,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
     08:57:08,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
     08:57:08,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    08:57:08,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
     08:57:08,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    08:57:08,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:601)
    08:57:08,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
     08:57:08,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    08:57:08,567 ERROR [STDERR] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot synchronize to any of these methods:
    public abstract stubs.BenefitLevel[] stubs.CarrierWSSEI.getActiveBenData() throws java.rmi.RemoteException

        OperationMetaData:
           qname={urn:CarrierWS/wsdl}getActiveBenData
          javaName=getActiveBenData
          style=rpc/literal
           oneWay=false
          soapAction=
        ReturnMetaData:
       xmlName=result
       partName=result
          xmlType={urn:CarrierWS/types/arrays/com/test/cas/carrier/plan/info}BenefitLevelArray
       javaType=com.test.cas.carrier.plan.info.BenefitLevel[]
       mode=OUT
      inHeader=false
       index=-1
         08:57:08,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ws.metadata.umdm.OperationMetaData.eagerInitialize(OperationMetaData.java:491)
         08:57:08,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ws.metadata.umdm.EndpointMetaData.eagerInitializeOperations(EndpointMetaData.java:557)
        08:57:08,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ws.metadata.umdm.EndpointMetaData.initializeInternal(EndpointMetaData.java:541)
          08:57:08,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ws.metadata.umdm.EndpointMetaData.setServiceEndpointInterfaceName(EndpointMetaData.java:220)
          08:57:08,567 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxrpc.client.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:345)
          08:57:08,567 ERROR [STDERR]     ... 33 more
```

My Web client code is as follows :

```
     <%@page import="java.util.Hashtable"%>
      <%@page import="javax.naming.*,com.q4.*,javax.xml.rpc.Stub,stubs.CarrierWS,stubs.CarrierWSSEI,stubs.CarrierWSSEI_Impl"%>
     <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
      <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
     <head>
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
          <title>JSP Page</title>
        </head>
       <body>
          <h1>Hello World!</h1>
          <%


         try
                           {
                        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext( );
                        CarrierWS carrierws = (CarrierWS)ic.lookup("java:comp/env/service/CarrierWS");
                out.println("========================" + carrierws);
                 CarrierWSSEI sei = carrierws.getCarrierWSSEIPort();
                  out.println("Invoking the service please wait ............." + carrierws.getCarrierWSSEIPort());
                ((Stub)sei)._setProperty(Stub.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,"http://localhost:8080/TestWS3WAR/CarrierWS");
                out.println("Invoking the service please wait ............." + sei.getActiveBenData().length);

             }
               catch(Exception e)
                                  {
                 out.println("Exception occurred : " + e.getMessage());
                  e.printStackTrace();
             }

             %>
        </body>
   </html>
```

Please help me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least in Jboss 5.0.1 GA the user defined datatypes cannot be returned in web service.

The user defined data types have to be converted to String or String array and vice versa.